# VS 2013 Watch Window- No Automatic Refreshing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, watch

I have an `std::stack` member, which holds pointers to a class with the following members:

```
std::vector<char> symbols;
size_t index;
```

I would like to watch the contents of `symbols`, which is at the top of the stack. Furthermore, I want to view ten of the characters, starting from `index`.

Therefore, I use the following expression:

`&this->the_stack.top()->symbols.operator[](this->the_stack.top()->index), 10`

However, each time I advance to the next break point, it seems my expression invalidates, which requires me to click the refresh button, along with another click to expand the result of the expression.

I followed [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ecfxd9.aspx) instructions to no avail. Is there any other method to enable automatic refreshing of the watch window?

**Edit:** I've discovered that VS allows to add the `ac` format specifier, but that doesn't seem to work for C++.

Comment: Just use vector. It's easier.